# How can I serve static files / a directory in hyper?

Tags: server, rust, hyper

I want to serve some static files (.js, .css, ...) from my hyper server.
Currently the only way I can think of is inlining the files as strings / load them on startup.
Is there a better way to directly serve an entire directory or selected files?

Comment: In real world deployment, your `nginx` or `caddy` will serve the files anyways, so I wouldn't worry to much about this and setup a reverse proxy instead.

Comment: @JanNilsFerner I respectfully disagree with such a broad pronouncement. Remember that Rust is a systems language, the kind of language you would *write NGINX in*. Who is to say that OP isn't attempting to write such a layer as that?

Comment: @Shepmaster Agreed, Rust would be the ideal language to write a reverse proxy. Note that I meant my comment to be interpreted as a pragmatical advice, i.e. I assume OP is probably not writing the next nginx and just wants to do some low level networking, in which case I would recommend to not reinvent the wheel and use his code together with other proved solutions.

Comment: I'd prefer having it in one place. Other frameworks allowed to simply map paths to directories. Using nginx is a good suggestion tho. But I'll try to do it in hyper first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After typing in the words "hyper static" into [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/hyper-staticfile), the first result was [hyper-staticfile](https://crates.io/crates/hyper-staticfile). The project's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/stephank/hyper-staticfile) has an [examples directory](https://github.com/stephank/hyper-staticfile/tree/554215012b589288750406362527b6e94d5464b7/examples), with one such example:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate hyper_staticfile;
extern crate tokio_core;

// This example serves the docs from target/doc/hyper_staticfile at /doc/
//
// Run `cargo doc && cargo run --example doc_server`, then
// point your browser to http://localhost:3000/

use futures::{Future, Stream, future};
use hyper::Error;
use hyper::server::{Http, Request, Response, Service};
use hyper_staticfile::Static;
use std::path::Path;
use tokio_core::reactor::{Core, Handle};
use tokio_core::net::TcpListener;

type ResponseFuture = Box<Future<Item=Response, Error=Error>>;

struct MainService {
    static_: Static,
}

impl MainService {
    fn new(handle: &Handle) -> MainService {
        MainService {
            static_: Static::new(handle, Path::new("target/doc/")),
        }
    }
}

impl Service for MainService {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = ResponseFuture;

    fn call(&self, req: Request) -> Self::Future {
        if req.path() == "/" {
            let res = Response::new()
                .with_status(hyper::StatusCode::MovedPermanently)
                .with_header(hyper::header::Location::new("/hyper_staticfile/"));
            Box::new(future::ok(res))
        } else {
            self.static_.call(req)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    let addr = "127.0.0.1:3000".parse().unwrap();
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr, &handle).unwrap();

    let http = Http::new();
    let server = listener.incoming().for_each(|(sock, addr)| {
        let s = MainService::new(&handle);
        http.bind_connection(&handle, sock, addr, s);
        Ok(())
    });

    println!("Doc server running on http://localhost:3000/");
    core.run(server).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: looking good. Only problem currently is that the return values don't match. `hyper-static` uses `type Future = Box<Future<Item = Response, Error = Error>>` while I use `type Future = futures::future::FutureResult<Response, Error>`